# Firebase IOS - Impersonate User

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am wanting to add to my iOS app the ability for sysadmin to login as another user as some bugs can only be recreated with certain users accounts and data.

I see the SDK has a custom token login (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) can than be utilised.

I tried getting a token using firebase admin sdk
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#python)
However that token when passed in via the SDK is rejected as being invalid.

Is this possible or do I have to implement this in a different way ? , currently my firebase rules are along these lines.

```
"rules": {
         "users":
     {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
                      }
      },
      "races":
     {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
                      }
      },
```

Do I simply need to redefine the rules to allow for a superuser access and then within the app use that users userid?